# Kibana showing query result search error

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, kibana

I have used Kibana timelion plugin to do some query and make some time series data.
This is my query
`.es(index='linux_cpu-*', metric='avg:CPU(%)', split='Hostname:5')`
I didn't find anything wrong with this query but just could not understand why it could not generate the desired result. Then, when I cross check with elasticsearch data log, I found the following stating search parse error.

```
[2016-06-26 23:32:43,290][DEBUG][action.search            ] [Bentley Wittman] [linux_cpu-2015.01.21][4], node[rtIRvgffRha3nFqYhjh8YA], [P], v[2], s[STARTED], a[id=xIKFCsvnRKaGqt7XyJtHNg]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@148c67f] lastShard [true]
RemoteTransportException[[Bentley Wittman][172.16.1.238:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1420096382918,"lte":1422689282919,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[],"filter":{}}},"aggs":{"q":{"meta":{"type":"split"},"filters":{"filters":{"*":{"query_string":{"query":"*"}}}},"aggs":{"Hostname":{"meta":{"type":"split"},"terms":{"field":"Hostname","size":5},"aggs":{"time_buckets":{"meta":{"type":"time_buckets"},"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1w","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","extended_bounds":{"min":1420096382918,"max":1422689282919},"min_doc_count":0},"aggs":{"avg(CPU(%))":{"avg":{"field":"CPU(%)"}}}}}}}}},"size":0}]]; nested: IllegalStateException[Field data loading is forbidden on [Hostname]];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1420096382918,"lte":1422689282919,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[],"filter":{}}},"aggs":{"q":{"meta":{"type":"split"},"filters":{"filters":{"*":{"query_string":{"query":"*"}}}},"aggs":{"Hostname":{"meta":{"type":"split"},"terms":{"field":"Hostname","size":5},"aggs":{"time_buckets":{"meta":{"type":"time_buckets"},"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1w","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","extended_bounds":{"min":1420096382918,"max":1422689282919},"min_doc_count":0},"aggs":{"avg(CPU(%))":{"avg":{"field":"CPU(%)"}}}}}}}}},"size":0}]]; nested: IllegalStateException[Field data loading is forbidden on [Hostname]];
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:855)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:654)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:620)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field data loading is forbidden on [Hostname]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService$1.build(IndexFieldDataService.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:275)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceParser.config(ValuesSourceParser.java:209)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.TermsParser.parse(TermsParser.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:176)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorParsers.parseAggregators(AggregatorParsers.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationParseElement.parse(AggregationParseElement.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:838)
    ... 12 more
```

Does anyone know what does that mean and how should I solve it?

Comment: The exact error is `Field data loading is forbidden on [Hostname]` which means that `Hostname` is probably either an analyzed field or `fielddata` is explicitly disabled (which was the default in Logstash 2.1 if you're using it). Can you update your question with your mapping?

Comment: Oh, that gives me a hint. And I have found that Hostname.raw can be a way to work around. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you have a `raw` field, then that's the one to use for that purpose and you won't get that error anymore. [Related issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15267)

Comment: However, when I trun to raw field, it sometimes give me another error of the following. Does that mean I have too may data in loading?
EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4@9474a on EsThreadPoolExecutor[search, queue capacity = 1000, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@1aa8ac1[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 7289]]]

Comment: It simply means you are running too many search requests and your ES cluster can't keep up with the pace. Or your queries are too slow and are running for too long.

Comment: Are there any ways that I can improve the condition?